# PPTP and Split Routing

Tags: encryption, vpn, pptp

If I uncheck the "use default gateway on remote network" to be able to browse local shares and the internet at the same time, does that void encryption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you uncheck that your traffic will be unencrypted.